# Ease-in-out function doesn't work, what to do?

Tags: html, css, button, opacity

All my buttons have an ease-in-out function. They work all, only my social buttons doesn't work properly. They give the opacity, but not the ease-in-out of 3s.

This is what I have:

```
<div class="contact-links">
<a class="fb" href="https://www.facebook.com/cgiphart" target="_blank"><img src="images/icon_fb.png" width="40px" height="40px"></a>
<a class="da" href="https://www.veavictis.deviantart.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/icon_da.png" width="40px" height="40px"></a>
</div>

.contact-links 
{
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
   -webkit-transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
    transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
}


.contact-links a:hover
{

    opacity: 0.5;

}
```

Comment: `.contact-links { opacity: 0; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Target the transitioning on the Anchor elements , and add an default opacity for the non-hover state.

```
.contact-links a {
    opacity:1;
    position:absolute;
    float:left;    -webkit-transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
    transition:all .3s ease-in-out; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a value for `opacity` on `.contact-links`, otherwise you are transitioning from an unknown value, so no keyframes can be extrapolated and the transition will not be implemented.

You also need to define the `transition` on the elements being animated. The below CSS should work:

```
.contact-links a{
    opacity:1; /* <-- any transitioning property needs a starting value */
    -webkit-transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
    transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
}  
.contact-links a:hover{
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```